# no such partition. grub rescue>

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I had 2 versions of ubuntu installed in single system. 12.04 and 13.04 on separate partitions.

I wanted to delete partition containing 12.04.

I used 'disc' software to do the job. Whether I successfully deleted it I don't know. Meanwhile I deleted partition named 'swap'.

While rebooting, I'm getting 'no such partition   grub rescue>.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on your system. If that fails, post back with the URL that the utility should give you.

Comment: How can i install BOOT REPAIR without booting the device? @Rod Smith

Comment: Use an Ubuntu emergency/live CD.